# Confusion over naming Line and Ray

Tags: geometry

> <-A-----------B--------------C->

A line is passing through points A, B and C.

As far I know, here :

Line: **AC**

Segment: **AB, BC and AC**

Ray: **BA and BC**

My confusion is about:

In case of segment we are considering **point A and C as end point.**
Now can I take, in case of Ray, **A as an end point**, and write, 
Ray: **AB or AC**

Can I write Line **AC** as **AB** ???

Thank you.

Comment: There are different symbols for segment, line, ray and length of segment (even not official symbols, but some of them are common).

Comment: If the 3 points are colinear, you can write the same line in many ways: $\overleftrightarrow{AB},\overleftrightarrow{AC},\overleftrightarrow{BC},\overleftrightarrow{CB},\overleftrightarrow{CA},\overleftrightarrow{BA}$. They represent the same line.

Comment: Please explain, sir.

Comment: For segment, the situation changes: $\overline{AB}=\overline{BA}$ but $\overline{AB}\neq\overline{AC}$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The line can be defined equivalently through any 2 distinct points on it. So $AC, AB, BC, CA, CB, BA$ all refer to the same line. Segments are uniquely identified by 2 points, segment $AB$ is the same as $BA$ but it's different than $AC, BC$. Finally for a ray the order in which you give the points matters, so $AB$ is the opposite ray to $BA$.
More formally you can define a line parametrically as the affine linear combination of two points $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$(1-\lambda)A + \lambda B, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$
You can define a line segment as the convex linear combination of two points:
$$(1-\lambda)A + \lambda B, \lambda \in [0,1]$$
Finally you can define a ray as an affine linear combination where $\lambda$ is additionally restricted to be non-negative:
$$(1-\lambda)A + \lambda B, \lambda \in [0,+\infty)$$

Comment: Can AC be a ray here

Comment: $AC$ can be a ray, and it covers the same set of points as $AB$. Note that just writing $AB$ doesn't clarify whether that is a line segment, a line or a ray. You need to explicitly state it.